# Index out of bounds Matlab

Tags: algorithm, matlab

i have to keep the RBG of a image in 3 different vectors (one for every colour). Then ,for all the vectors, i count the number of apparences of every pixel in the [0;255] interval found in them.I have to split this [0;255] (pixel range) interval into N intervals , and make the sum of every interval, using the following formula :

> [x * 256/N ; x * 256/N + 256/N )

with x <= N

N is greater of equal to 16.
So far , my code works for N that divide 256 , for the rest i get "Index out of bound " . 
I think the formula implementation is somehow wrong. but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: on first look, consider using `histc` or `accumarray`

Comment: @Amro i have to complete this task without using histc

Comment: so what are you allowed to use?

Comment: @Amro anything besides matlab implemented functions (zeros , int16 are exceptions because they don't make the task much easier)

Answer (score 1):

You get 'index out of bounds' because of the rounding in `int16(256/N)`.

```
N = 16 ... int16(256/N) = 16 (no rounding)
N = 19 ... int16(256/N) = 13 (13.47 is rounded to 13)
N = 20 ... int16(256/N) = 13 (12.80 is rounded to 13)
```

Sometimes the result is rounded to next smaller value and sometimes to the next greater value(that is when you get out of bounds).

Solution: use `floor(256/N)` instead of `int16(256/N)`.